# Sails.js testing with mocha only runs one test not two

Tags: node.js, sails.js, mocha.js

I followed the sails.js testing example at http://sailsjs.org/#!/documentation/concepts/Testing . I have got it to run, but it only runs one test. The command line in package.json script.test is:

mocha test/bootstrap.test.js test/unit/**/*.test.js

"test/unit/**/*.test.js" should be catching 2 tests, UsersControllers.test.js and Users.test.js . It is only running Users.test.js . And yes, both tests are in the test/unit/ directory.

[image: CLI Screen Shot]

What am I doing wrong here ?

Comment: Can you provide any more detail information? Because it should work well based on your current information.

Comment: Looks like you are using `describe.only()` as it is written in docs. You need to use just `describe()`

Comment: Bulkin That would be it, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

After copying the documented test cases from the sails js docs, make sure to change the following line in the User.test.js file

```
describe.only('UsersModel', function() {
```

to

```
describe('UsersModel', function() {
```

then you should see the controller test as well.